# Qual a finalidade do Transient e Volatile no Java?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

As vezes quando vou declarar meus atributos noto o `transient` e o `volatile`. Tenho as seguintes dúvidas

- O `transient` e `volatile` são modificadores de acesso?
- Qual a finalidade de utilizá-los?

Exemplo:

```
transient String a;
volatile String b;
```

Comment: Existe isso em java? huahuahua nunca tinha visto. +1

Comment: Existe sim, rs @DiegoF

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Eles não são modificadores de acesso, mas modificam como a Máquina Virtual Java trata os atributos em tempo de execução.

## Atributos transientes

Um atributo transiente significa que ele não será serializado ou desserializado juntamente com os demais atributos de um determinado objeto.

Serialização é o processo no qual os atributos de um objeto (estado) são convertidos, um a um, numa sequência de bytes. Desserialização é o processo inverso, onde bytes são lidos e um novo objeto é construído.

As aplicações mais comuns são:

- Transmissão de objetos pela rede. Muito usado em APIs como:

  - JNDI: acesso a um diretório de objetos
  - RMI: invocação de método remoto
  - Servlets: distribuição de objetos na sessão entre os nós de um cluster
- Salvar objetos em arquivos ou bancos de dados. Esta geralmente é uma abordagem *ad hoc* para guardar configurações ou estado de forma "fácil"

Você define explicitamente que não quer serializar um determinado atributo com `transient` basicamente nos casos a seguir:

- Você quer serializar a classe, mas um atributo de um certo tipo (classe) não é serializável, portanto o processo iria falhar.
- O valor do atributo é algum tipo de cache e você não precisa dele, portanto isso economiza memória e processamento.
- O atributo representa alguma entidade local e não faz sentido transmiti-la, por exemplo uma conexão com o banco de dados (`Connection`) ou qualquer referência a um recurso que precisa ser aberto e fechado.

É importante também mencionar que esse atributo não tem efeito se você sobrescrever os métodos [`writeObject` e `readObject`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html), que habilitam, respectivamente, a serialização e desserialização manual dos objetos.

## Atributos voláteis

Trabalhar com várias *threads* causa muito mais dor de cabeça do que se possa imaginar. Isso ocorre porque frequentemente várias threads precisam acessar e modificar objetos compartilhados.

Imagine o seguinte cenário:

```
long i = 0;
void thread1() {
  ...
  i++;
  ...
}
void thread2() {
  ...
  if (i == 1) {
    fazAlgo();
  }
  ...
}
```

No exemplo, as duas threads acessam a mesma variável. Assumindo que a leitura da `thread2` ocorre, numa sequência de tempo, exatamente após o incremento da `thread1`, você acha que pode ocorrer algum problema de concorrência, considerando que o incremento **parece uma operação atômica**?

Uma análise ingênua diria que está tudo bem com as *threads* pois as duas executam operações atômicas de escrita e leitura, logo `fazAlgo` seria executado sem problemas.

**Errado.**

Cada *thread* **pode** estar sendo executada em um processador diferente. Cada processador **pode** ter um *cache* próprio. Variáveis são lidas e gravadas primeiro no cache local antes de irem para a memória principal. Então, **é possível** que a segunda *thread* leia o valor antigo da variável.

O cenário problemático ocorreria assim:

1. T1 lê o valor de `i = 0` da memória principal e faz o incremento; o novo valor `i = 1` é armazenado no cache local, mas não na memória principal.
2. T2 lê o valor de `i = 0` da memória principal e não entra no `if`.

Pior que isto, variáveis de 64 bits como `long` e `double` podem ter sua escrita em memória dividida pela JVM em dois ciclos de 32 bits, o que poderia levar uma leitura completamente corrompida de seus valores.

**Tais cenários são relativamente raros, mas extremamente difíceis de identificar em softwares complexos, causando aquele tipo de problema intermitente e ocasional que acaba sendo varrido para debaixo do tapete.**

A solução, neste caso, é simples:

```
volatile long i = 0;
```

Um atributo volátil tem garantia de que o valor atualizado estará sempre disponível para outras *threads*, sendo gravado na memória principal assim que atualizado, de forma atômica.

Isso significa que, sempre que o valor for modificado em um processador, ocorrerá um *flush* para a memória principal, portanto as outras *threads* vão ver sempre o valor mais atualizado e não um possível valor defasado.

Claro que isso não é gratuito. Fazer o `flush` do cache para a memória principal penaliza o desempenho, afinal existe uma razão para os fabricantes de hardware colocarem caches nos processadores. É muito mais rápido acessar um registrador ou cache primário do que acessar a memória RAM.

Uma solução alternativa seria usar métodos de sincronização como um bloco `synchronized` ou variáveis atômicas como `AtomicLong`, os quais podem ser necessários quando há modificação concorrente, mas que são mais lentos.

No caso de escrita concorrente, como bem lembrado pelo Rafael na outra resposta, uma variável `volatile` ainda poderia incorrer em condição de corrida pois as duas threads podem ler o mesmo valor da memória principal, e o valor final dependeria de qual das threads escreveria ele por último.

Curiosamente, a classe [`AtomicLong`](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.java/?v=source) usa `volatile`:

```
private volatile long value;
```

Qual a diferença então? Ocorre que as classes atômicas usam a técnica conhecida como [*compare and swap*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap), isto é, a operação de atualização da variável é condicionado ao valor antigo. Por exemplo, cada thread envia uma instrução parecido com "atualize o valor 1 para 2". O processador então garante que a variável somente será atualizada para `2` se o valor dela for `1`, caso contrário a operação falha. Digamos que o valor agora era `3` e a operação falhou. A thread agora tenta novamente com "atualize o valor 3 para 2" e assim por diante até obter sucesso. Esta técnica garante que a atualização segura do valor em memória.

Comment: Excelente explicação, obrigado.

Comment: Considerando a nova resposta, acredito que esta aqui irá requerer algum tipo de retificação.

Comment: @Piovezan Valeu pelo toque. Pisei na bola na hora do exemplo, tinha que ser modificação e leitura e não duas modificações mesmo. Acho que na época eu tentei deixar muito simples e acabou ficando incorreto. Quanto à operação de incremento ser atômica, não foi minha intenção confirmar isto de forma alguma. Fica implícito na resposta que isto é algo que as pessoas presumem, mas lendo o passo a passo da execução eu deixei bem claro que a operação é dividida em leitura e atualização. Resposta atualizada!

Answer (score 6):

Com relação ao Transient é o que todos disseram acima, não tenho nada a acrescentar, contudo, é preciso ter em mente que um atributo volatile tem a função de não guardar caches, o que acaba auxiliando o problema da situação abaixo:

```
volatile int i = 0;                                                              
void thread1() {                                                                 
  i++;                                                                 
}                                                                 
void thread2() {                                                                 
  i++;                                                                 
}
```

Porém, esta solução não elimina o problema de condição de corrida, pois, se ambas as threads tentarem incrementar ao mesmo tempo a variável, o volatile não impede que este valor mantenha-se errado. Para isto, é necessário sincronizar este trecho da incrementação como uma zona crítica.

Um uso mais apropriado para esta variável seria algo do tipo:

```
public class Foo extends Thread {
    private volatile boolean close = false;
    public void run() {
        while(!close) {
            // do work
        }
    }
    public void close() {
        close = true;
        // interrupt here if needed
    }
}
```

Comment: De fato o incremento [não é atômico](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25168062/why-is-i-not-atomic). Exceto para [variáveis locais](http://madbean.com/2003/mb2003-44/), que não são relevantes para concorrência.

Answer (score 4):

Transient:

Quando definido como transient significa que o campo não será serializado pelo java.

Post explicando melhor https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910374/why-does-java-have-transient-variables

Volatile:

Quando definido um campo como volatile, este campo será visto de forma compartilhada/atualizada por todas as threads que utilizarem esta variavel.

Melhores explicações em: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/volatile.html

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor? Quem não souber inglês(como eu) vai ficar sem entender muito a respeito das definições.