# Ignorar atributo no POST usando Retrofit

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Gostaria de saber como ignorar um atributo de um model em uma requisição `POST` com Retrofit. Em requisições `GET` eu quero trazer todos os atributos, mas em requisições `POST` preciso mandar o objeto sem o `id` por exemplo.

Exemplo de *Model*:

```
public class Model {

  int id;               // ignorar este atributo
  String atributo1;
  String atributo2;
  String atributo3;     // ignorar este atributo

  // ... getters and setters

}
```

Exemplo de *Service*:

```
public interface ModelService {

  @POST("resources")
  Call<Model> create(@Body Model model) // enviar objeto sem id e atributo3

}
```

Exemplo de execução:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
         .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
         .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
         .build();

ModelService modelService = retrofit.create(ModelService.class);
Call<Model> call = modelService.create(collection);

call.enqueue(new Callback<Model>() {

  // ... onResponse / onFailure

});
```

Existe essa possibilidade ou preciso implementar de outra forma? Ou talvez devo tratar isso no *backend*?

Comment: por curiosidade, pq você quer ignorar o id da sua entidade ? ele sempre estava saindo como 0 e isso estava te atrapalhando ?

Comment: Você tem razão, eu achei que o id 0 estava impendindo o registro de ser criado na API, mas fiz um teste rápido e funcionou. O problema é que em uma requisição `GET` vem um ou outro valor que não é do modelo, mas que é útil. Por exemplo, uma tarefa é realizada em uma cidade, então em uma requisição à `/tarefas` trago o id e o nome da cidade no json, mas o nome da cidade não faz parte da tarefa, apenas o id da cidade. Assim, numa requisição `POST`, se o nome da cidade for no body o registro não é criado. Talvez o correto seja tratar isso no backend, não tenho certeza.

Comment: Para manter o alto nível e fluência da sua api, você deveria devolver o  objeto Tarefa com uma referência do objeto Cidade. Mas devolver o id da cidade não é errado, só é menos fluente, ambas estão absolutamente corretas.

Comment: Então seria interessante trazer só o nome da cidade, já que é importante nessa requisição, e uma referência (link) para o objeto cidade? Isso é hypermedia, certo? E quanto a trazer o objeto Cidade dentro do objeto Tarefa? Vi alguns exemplos assim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se você deseja que o `id` não apareça no JSON serializado, uma forma é usar o `transient`. Veja:

```
private transient int id;
```

Veja mais detalhes sobre o `transient` [na documentação](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Finer-Points-with-Objects) e também nessa pergunta sobre [qual a finalidade do `Transient` e `Volatile` no Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/116047/qual-a-finalidade-do-transient-e-volatile-no-java).

Ou também, se preferir, pode usar [`@Expose`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html). Veja:

```
@Expose
private int id;
```

Sendo assim, basta utilizar o método `excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation()`. Veja:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
```

Comment: As duas forma funcionaram perfeitamente! Mas como só preciso ignorar os atributos no POST, a segunda forma ficou melhor. Muito obrigado!