# Colocar variável de tempo no botão Voltar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, thread

Galera, Boa noite.
Preciso de uma ajudinha, estou com o seguinte código. Pois preciso parar a Thread quando o botão voltar for clicado.

```
private void timeGame() {

    t = new Timer();
    t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //runOnUiThread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    if (timeCounter > 0){

                        timeCounter--;
                       textoTime.setText((Integer.toString((timeCounter))));

                    }else{

                        t.cancel();
                        startActivity(new Intent(QuestionsSolo.this, GameOver.class));
                        QuestionsSolo.this.finish();

                    }


                    }

            });

        }
    }, 1000, 1000);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
//funcionando, ficou assim.    
t.cancel();
startActivity(new Intent(QuestionsSolo.this, TypeFragmentSolo.class));
}
```

}

Comment: Não precisa colocar (resolvido) na pergunta Guil. O fato de você aprovar uma resposta significa que a pergunta foi resolvida. Abraço!

Comment: Malz, não sabia. Abraços mano. Valeu ai, de novo. kkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Opção 1**

Você pode usar um [`volatile`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/116080/15361) como atributo para controle.

```
private volatile boolean run = true;

...
private void timeGame() {
 ...

   if (timeCounter > 0 && run){ // <-- atributo de controle

      timeCounter--;
      textoTime.setText((Integer.toString((timeCounter))));

   }else{

      t.cancel();// <-- cancela se o atributo for false
      startActivity(new Intent(QuestionsSolo.this, GameOver.class));
      QuestionsSolo.this.finish();

    }
```

Depois no `onBackPressed()` você altera:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    run = false;
}
```

Desta forma ele irá cancelar quando o atributo `run` for false.

**Opção 2**

Ao invés de colocar o `Timer` dentro da função `timeGame()`

```
private void timeGame() {
      final Timer t = new Timer();

...
```

Você insere esse `Timer` como atributo da classe:

```
Timer t;
```

e na função você altera para:

```
 private void timeGame() {
      t = new Timer();

  ...
```

Com isso você conseguirá cancelar dentro do `onBackPressed()`:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   t.cancel();
}
```

Eu não testei nenhuma delas, mas acredito que ambas opções funcionam.

Comment: Fala Andrei, Bleeza? Só tu pra me salvar, Hahahha.. Ambas as opções não funcionam e funcionam, como assim?! Elas param o contador, porém bloqueia o botão voltar. O contador para porém não volta. Mas ai, Tarammmm.. Mandei um Intente após o t.cancel(). jogando pro fragment que queria, ai ficou top. kkkk

Comment: @GuilDraco ah! Pode crer! Mas porque será que trava né?...  Que bom que deu certo! =)

Comment: @GuilDraco vou fazer uns testes mais tarde! Abraço!